# How to calibrate camera using react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-camera2, camera-calibration, ios-camera

We have requirement of capturing photo from app, but for that external light source is attached near to camera of phone. Using which we have to calibrate camera for getting better image.

Is there any code snippet or methodology which can be use to calibrate camera of Android or Apple phones using React Native.

Has anyone done similar before?